# Return an IEnumerable with variable number of columns WebApi

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, ienumerable, anonymous-types

I have a request coming with with some filtering parameters and a list of possible calculations to perform. My code is filtering my database and then grouping it by a Date field.

At this point it is supposed to run through the dataset and perform the requested calculations, then join them based on the Date field and return this to my front end which will graph the different calculations against each other.

My question is if there is a way to have Web Api return an IEnumerable where the number and name of the columns are unknown until the function is called, or if the only way to do this is to create a class to represent each data point where the calculation properties will be null unless called for?

Comment: Using ODATA is an option? http://www.odata.org/blog/how-to-use-web-api-odata-to-build-an-odata-v4-service-without-entity-framework/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could return IEnumerable.  Or you can serialize them in the controller to a string and return a string.